# Querying Property of a relationship in Neo4j using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have two nodes in **neo4j** named A and DEF. A and DEF are connected through a relationship named **DEFINITION**.This relationship has a property **named:description**(description of what is A).I want to run query like "what is A" which should fetch the property of the relationship **DEFINITION**.I tried out this query.But it is returning null.any leads?

```
match (l:A)-[h:DEFINITION]->(r:DEF)
return  h.description;
```

Comment: Do you get any results on this query `match (l:A)-[h:DEFINITION]->(r:DEF)
return l,h,r;` ?

Comment: No.Nothing is returned.Only this is what I am getting:(no changes, no records)

Comment: If you're looking through the neo4j browser I suggest that you only match on :A `match (l:A) return l` and expand this node. Do you then have any results?

Comment: Here it is returning the label named "A"

Comment: So if you break the query in separate queries like: `match (l:A) return l`, `match (r:DEF) return r`, `match ()-[h:DEFINITION]-() return h` do you have results on every query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the pattern actually exists in the graph. You said the property is `Description` but you are getting `description`, make sure your case matches what's actually there. Also double-check the direction of the relationship.

Comment: The property is:description actually.and trying to fetch the same.I have rechecked the graph pattern too

Comment: Okay, you said the nodes are named A and DEF, but your pattern shows these as labels on the nodes. Are these really labels, or properties on the nodes?

Comment: They are the labels of nodes.

Comment: Okay, so provided the case on those labels is correct (and on the relationship type as well), do a sanity check and match on the pattern and inspect the relationship and properties you expect to find: `MATCH path = (:A)-[:DEFINITION]-(:DEF) RETURN path`
`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing a sanitary check by running the query specified but sadly, I still have the same problem. and its returning:no changes, no records.

Comment: Then for some reason that pattern doesn't exist in the graph. The sanity check at least tells you there is no :A and :DEF node such that they are connected by a :DEFINITION relationship. Could be due to a typo, or casing, or some other problem with what was created vs what you're querying for. How much data is in the graph? For a small graph just do a `MATCH (n) RETURN n` in the browser and it will show all nodes and relationships. It's possible either the query you used to add these nodes didn't succeed, or what you created somehow doesn't match what you're querying for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
match (l:A)-[h:definition]->(r:DEF)
return  h.named
```